# Google script to download file on Form Submit

Tags: google-drive-api

thanks so much for helping me with this. I have next to no experience coding, so if you can help, please be as specific as possible.

I followed a tutorial to make this thing that runs when someone completes a form. The idea is simply to replace variables in a template doc with the form responses. This tutorial had it so that when the form was submitted, the template doc was saved as a PDF and then emailed.

However, I want to download the PDF to a drive on my computer, not email it. Is this even possible?

Here is my code:

```
var docTemplate = "1JZnLGe5eqIIHe0R7YkN3fsoscoyeQ70k1a_aoYEXdzI";
var docName = "WV MR Request ";

function onFormSubmit(e) {

var facility_name = e.values[8];
var date = e.values[10];
var cli_first = e.values[2];
var cli_last = e.values[3];
var dob = e.values[4];
var last4 = e.values[5];
var date_range = e.values[6];
var adv_name = e.values[9];
var pronoun = e.values[7];
var email_address = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();


var copyId = DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy(docName+' for '+cli_last +last4)
.getId();

var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);  

var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();  

copyBody.replaceText('keyFacilityName', facility_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDate', date);
copyBody.replaceText('keyCliFName', cli_first);
copyBody.replaceText('keyCliLName', cli_last);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDOB', dob);
copyBody.replaceText('keyLast4',last4);
copyBody.replaceText('keyDateRange', date_range);
copyBody.replaceText('keyAdvName', adv_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keyPronoun', pronoun);

copyDoc.saveAndClose();

var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");

var subject = "WV Rates Letter" +cli_last +last4;
var body = "See attached letter for " + cli_first + cli_last + "";
MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});

DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);  

}
```

Thanks for any help you can offer. I really thought this would be a simple task, but I can't find anything on google or this site.

Comment: yes its possible. what did you try so far? currently the question is only code you found, and asking to modify it. many samples and answers mention saving a file to Drive with apps script.

Comment: I know how to save a file to drive, that's not really the issue. I want to save a file to a local machine with the apps script. I tried to enable advanced drive and implement the 'download a file' examples that google gives in their documentation. But I either get an error or nothing happens. I haven't found a single class or method in the standard google script that even mentions downloading a file to a machine. I feel like the Blob object(?) might be the way to do it, but I can't make sense of that either.

Comment: it is imposible as the code is running on google servers not your machine. you would need to have a user click on a link.

Comment: Is that some sort of security feature that Google has built in? So that scripts can't start downloads without more direct input? Seems kind of odd to me that they don't allow you to start a download for a google doc, but they will automatically sync folders.

Comment: not at all. simply you would need magic to transfer the download from google servers (where the script runs) to your machine.